# strtotime() always returns same day of month but gets other parts of date correct

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I have a part of a simple web app that takes input from a JavaScript calendar picker, sends it to the server, and then the server converts it to a human readable time and echos it back out.

My HTML form ends up having a value formatted as MM/DD/YYYY.

When this gets POSTed to the server this PHP transforms it into a differet format (please note that I'm using CodeIgniter so `$this->input->post()` is the same as `$_POST[]`):

`php
$date = date('l, F n, Y', strtotime($this->input->post('date')));`

**Example input and output**

HTML text input will get a value of "04/21/2013".

PHP's strtotime() will echo back "Sunday, April 4, 2013".

No matter what date I put in there, strtotime() always gives me the correct date back **except for the day of the month** which *always* ends up being the same number as the number of the month (for example, any dates in May become "May 5, 2013" and so on).

## Update: Solved

As soon as I posted this I realized it was the 'n' in 'l, F n, Y' that caused the issue. Turning it to a 'j' fixed things. Sorry to waste everyone's time.

Comment: Could it be to do with how you're formatting it? F = A full textual representation of a month, such as January or March. n = Numeric representation of a month, without leading zeros. So it looks like you're setting the month twice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `j` for day of the month, not `n` which is the numeric month:

```
php $date = date('l, F j, Y', strtotime($this->input->post('date')));
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/1eF1Nk)

Comment: Thank you. I was just in the middle of answering my own question. I can't bleive I spent 2 days and it was staring me in the face this whole time. Now I feel like an idiot for even asking. (I'm going to accept your answer but it wants me to wait 10 minutes)

Comment: We've all spun our wheels over something like this at some point.

Answer (score 2):

See the documentation for date() here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Change the n in the first parameter of your date function to j and you will get the number of the day of the month.